# How can I Spring-ify my stand-alone (non Web Service) application?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a working stand-alone application, which uses Postgres, with the following
rough structure:

```
class myClass {

     public myClass( String filePath ) {...}

     public void calculate( ...args... ) {...}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          ...process args...
          new myClass(...).calculate(...)
     }
}
```

I am trying to convert this to a Spring Boot application to take advantage of
Spring JDBC.   Here's the rough structure, a modification of the above:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class myClass implements implements CommandLineRunner {

     public myClass( String filePath ) {...}

     public void calculate( ...args... ) {...}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run( myClass.class, args);
     }
     @Override
     public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
         ...process args...
         new myClass(...).calculate(...)
     }
}
```

When I try running this from Eclipse, I get the following error message:

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

Why is this happening, what can I do to fix it?   And, why is it even complaining about "WebApplication",
since I do not include anything having to do with Web or Controller in my `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to the error above by slightly modifying how I structured my `main` method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class myClass implements implements CommandLineRunner {

     public myClass( String filePath ) {...}

     public void calculate( ...args... ) {...}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication( myClass.class );
         application.setWebEnvironment( false );
         application.run( args );
     }
     @Override
         public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
             ...process args...
             this.calculate(...)   <<<=== Note change here, too
     }
}
```